# "Strange as it may sound" vs "Strange sound though it may be"

Tags: adjectives

I'm trying to write something and this question popped up.

Which would be more correct?

"Strange as it may sound ~" or "Strange sound though it may be ~"

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you mean *Strange though it may be*?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but since my mother language is not English, what's the difference between "Strange though it maybe" and "Strange sound though it maybe"? :)

Comment: The first talks about how something sounds, the second talks about a sound.

Answer (score 3):

The construction *X as it may VERB* (or *though it may VERB*) is an inversion which has the sense *Even though it may VERB X*.

Your two phrases accordingly have very different meanings:

- **Strange as it may sound** = Even though it sounds strange ... *You are conceding that what is stated in the main clause "sounds strange", that is, appears unlikely.*

  > Strange as it may sound, Mozart's letters are suffused with bathroom humor.
- **Strange sound though it may be** = Even though it is a strange sound ... *You are conceding that the physical sound you are about to describe in the main clause is a strange one.*

  > Strange sound though it may be, the tone of the basset horn seems to have been peculiarly attractive to the mature Mozart.

Answer (score 0):

The two phrases, "*strange as it may sound*" and "*strange though it may be*" are fairly common, and can be used pretty much interchangeable in most contexts. Both are correct, although the first one is [much more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Strange+as+it+may+sound%2C+Strange+though+it+may+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

- "*Strange as it may sound*," can be read as, "*what I'm about to tell you may sound strange, but…*" It implies that the audience is actually listening to the speaker, although this phrase is not limited to verbal communication.
- "*Strange though it may be*," can be read as "*it is strange that…*" It is actually suggesting that the statement being made is in fact strange, not simply that it sounds strange to the audience.

I don't think I've ever head anyone use the phrase, "*strange sound though it may be*," although it's not necessarily wrong. It would really only make sense if you're talking about a unusual noise, for example, "*I've become accustomed to hearing the foxes cry, a strange sound though it may be.*"

Answer (score 0):

*Strange sound though it may be* is not a formation that is generally used by most English speakers, but it is something that we could understand as having a meaning like the construction *as strange a sound as it may be*. This construction would say that the sound under discussion is something you concede to be strange, but that you wish to comment on some characteristic it has which is nevertheless interesting or not strange. An example would be this: *As strange a sound as it may be, it is quite soothing to me.*

*Strange as it may sound* means *I realize that this sounds unlikely or unexpected, but it's true*, as used in a comment of this type: *Strange as it may sound, the Earth rotates faster at the Equator than it does in Canada.*